# Gmail says "Images are not displayed", but not "Always display images from"

Tags: email, gmail

My application is sending transactional email through Mandrill. If we include linked images, Gmail doesn't show them by default. That's normal. What's weird is that, in my test email to myself, it doesn't give me an option to "Always display images from" the address that sent the email.

[image: "Images are not displayed. Display images below"]

[Gmail's help document](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/8833?hl=en) doesn't even mention this as a possibility.

How can I get Gmail to give my users the option to always display images in my app's emails?

Comment: It might have something to do with the URL or the actual message, which you'll probably have to give us then. Though currently this question, although related to an application sending a mail, is actually about what Gmail does, and thus isn't on topic for [so] (it might be for [webapps.se]).

Comment: I thought about that, but it seemed like an odd fit over there, since it's not really about *using* a web app so much as interacting with it programmatically.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the internal logic of Gmail, not about programming.

Comment: @tripleee I disagree: this question is about how to generate an email that Gmail will accept correctly. Gmail provides an interface, and I'd like to correctly program against it. It's a common task in web programming, and an uncommon task in any other context. It fits the definition of covering "software tools commonly used by programmers" and being "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development".

Comment: This question being closed is the reason why StackOverflow is dying from over moderation.

Comment: Problem is that you are sending emails to yourself, which Gmail sees as suspicious, but doesn't offer the option to approve yourself as a sender (given it's yourself to approve). I have the same issue and wish they could fix it.

Comment: Wow @SamTso, I just lost 3 hours because of this exact problem. There is absolutely nothing about it on the web. I wish this question wasn't closed and your comment was the accepted answer.

Comment: Saaaaame here..