# Always display images in html email in gmail

Tags: php, wordpress, email, gmail

I am working on a wordpress cms. I have a little script which enable people to select posts and send it over email. The email consists of thumbnails of the selected posts. I receive them fine on my gmail email account. But just as links, not as images as they were intended to be. Everytime I have to click "display images below" then only it displays.

Earlier I remember that it used to give this option “Always display images from” but not anymore, all I see now is this. Currently the image links appear as any normal link eg. - [example link](http://stackoverflow.com)

[image: currently gmail gives this prompt]

Not that it is too much trouble to click "Display images below" link but it is nice when technology simply works, innit? So please let me know if you know of any particular reason this might be happening.

BTW, there was a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19060080/gmail-says-images-are-not-displayed-but-not-always-display-images-from) asked before but ended up with no solution. If it matters, Here is an ideal snippet from my processForm.php. Code was majorly inspired from [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/).

```
$to = "awesome_dude@gmail.com";
$subject = "NEW REPORT";
$headers = "From: staff <junior@awesomeness.com>" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= $_POST['message'];
$message .= '<br><br>';
$message .= $_POST ['client'];
$message .= '</body></html>';
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

UPDATE: I cleared the email from the filters in hope of getting the “Always display images from” option again but nopes, same reault.

Comment: I also need this feature as I do not want to lose the visual appeal of my work due to this when I pass it to my client. As my client will basically say "why does this look like spam" ?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? Or any more information you can provide?

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, in Gmail there is usually a 'Always display images from...' link right after the 'Display images below' image you have in your question. I'm guessing you've already clicked this once for your own emails? That would explain why it no longer appears...

If Gmail is not loading the images, perhaps the html code is not correct. The 'Display images...' might just be a courtesy by gmail, as it recognizes them as images.

You'll need to post your resulting html to know for sure. [Litmus Scope](https://litmus.com/scope/) is a good free tool to pull the resulting html out of Gmail.

Comment: i tested with litmus and the images appear fine, which means the code is correct. It is a minimal amount of code, I have already given.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are not getting the images as you want is related to privacy protection. When you use images on an email you have 2 options, embed the images in the email wich results in a larger size email, or load the images from the server.

When you link the images gmail (and many other email clients) detect the linked images and asks the user for confirmation to download. This may sound useless to us as developers, but email marketers as well as spammers tend to include images with unique tracking codes for example . Do you see the privacy issue on this image?

If you want to properly embed the images on your emails check out this tutorial:
[PHP Email: Using Embedded Images in HTML Email](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Email-Using-Embedded-Images-in-HTML-Email-P113.html), it's quite old, but may get you on track.

Comment: The link that you pointed me to, it is very hard to understand due to terrible grammar and poor layout, it kind of defeats your point. Additionally it uses stuffs like `chunk_split` and `base64_encode` and stuff which is too irrelevant and strays far off the point. I will do my own research though, thanks.

Comment: sorry for that, I didn't read the article, I went straight to the sourcecode. The basic idea is that first you need to attach the images to email, second you reference the images to the attached image. Try to focus on the image link and attachment part (Lines 31-32, 59 and 63-69 specially).